# nginx перенаправлять на другой сайт, если запрос не к статике

Tags: nginx

Каким образом возможно составить правило для конфига таким образом.

- Если запрос не к статичному файлу, перенаправляем пользователя на третий сайт
- Если запрос к файлу и файл не не найден. Перенаправить пользователя на третий сайт

Comment: [nginx serve from static if not found try reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28572392/2881286)

Comment: Понимать бы что написано... Как определить что файл не найден? Как определить что запрос не к статичному файлу?

Comment: в ответе указана явная настройка. [try_files](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)